# How to fight closures in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to iteratively built all possible plots of my data, colored by each of the column in a table.

So far I have this code:

```
  # ----- next is a function taken from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/ 
  # --- not relevant to the question, my code is in the end of the snippet
  library(ggplot2)
  multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  library(grid)

  # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

  numPlots = length(plots)

  # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
  if (is.null(layout)) {
    # Make the panel
    # ncol: Number of columns of plots
    # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
    layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                     ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }

  if (numPlots==1) {
    print(plots[[1]])

  } else {
    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
      # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
      matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

      print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                      layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------
temp23_before6 <- data.frame(TIME = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                         VALUE = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                         P = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1),
                         D = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
i <- 1
p <- list()
for (col in names(temp23_before6)) {
  l <-length(unique(temp23_before6[, col]))
  if (l < 20 && l > 1) {
    cc <- col
    p[[i]] <- ggplot(temp23_before6, aes(TIME, VALUE, colour=factor(temp23_before6[, cc]))) + 
                geom_point() + labs(title=col)

    i <- i + 1
  }
}
multiplot(plotlist = p, cols = as.integer(sqrt(i)))
```

Unfortunately `cc` is not changed due to closure, and I receive all the plots exactly the same. The usual trick which works with other languages - assign `col` to a local variable - doesn't work. How do I make it work in R?

**Update** Updated code so the example can be ran in a new R env. I expect these four plots to be of different color. The two of them `Time` and `Value` should be obviously of single color, and the other two `P` and `D` should have different colors, determined by `P = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1), D = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)`, so `D` should have 5 different colors, and `P` should have only 3

Comment: `c` is an object that already exists in R and shouldn't be overwritten. Given that you're writing a `for` loop, there is no difference between "local" and "global" variables because you don't enter a different scope. I'm failing to see why you need to assign `col` to `c` at all, given that it's only called once and could just be called using `col`. Does your code work if you replace `colour=factor(temp23_before6[, c])` with `colour=factor(temp23_before6[, col])`?

Comment: @Batanichek Totally missed that. But this doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: @brittenb No, if I replace it with `col` it still does the same. The usual trick in other languages (C#, Java) is to make a local variable for a closure, so for each for run there will be a separate local variable (so you have the same number of local variables as there in the array total, so each for run separately closes over it's own `c` instance). But appearently that does not work in R

Comment: Can you paste the actual error that you're getting please?

Comment: @brittenb I do not have any error. I just receive all the plots the same, when I expect them to be different (actually the same plots with different fields coloured)

Comment: Let's start with not naming variables after built-in functions.

Comment: What outcome would you expect? You're getting exactly what you're telling R to give you. Loop through each column in `temp23_before6` and see if the there are 2-19 unique values in that column. If so, plot the data with `TIME` on the x axis and `VALUE` on the y-axis. The colors of the points should be determined by the current column. At no point do you tell R to use different data.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Done, please see update. I've also made an example standalone, capable of being ran in a new environment

Comment: @brittenb I want color to be different in each run, that's why I am using `col` in a for loop, isn't that obvious? And I understand that my code is not working as I expect, that's why I am asking here about that

Comment: Ah, I see. You want them to be different colors, but currently they are not? Your question implied you were getting an error, but your comment implied the code was running but producing graphs with nothing more than different colored points. In reality, you're just getting the exact same plots when you desire plots with different colors?

Comment: @brittenb Yes. Please see my update

Comment: `force()` to force evaluation?

Comment: @MartinMorgan Not sure. Where should I write it? If I use it inside the loop, it does not give me anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has more to do with programming within the [hadlyverse](http://adolfoalvarez.cl/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-hadleyverse/). We make two changes, 1) add `aes_string` to allow evaluation within the `ggplot` call, and 2) clean up the legend to be named by the coloring column:

```
p[[i]] <- ggplot(temp23_before6, aes_string("TIME", "VALUE", 
            colour=factor(temp23_before6[,cc]))) + 
            geom_point() + labs(title=col) + scale_colour_discrete(name=cc)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain briefly what `aes_string` is doing differently that forces it to "remember" what the color assignments were? Just for my own information.

Comment: @brittenb it allows for standard evaluation as opposed to the interactive NSE mode. Here's more https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/rggplot2-tip-aes_string/

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with how `ggplot` references its colors when printing the plot. I'm not entirely sure about this, but let's look at an example.

```
temp23_before6 <- data.frame(TIME = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                             VALUE = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                             P = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1),
                             D = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
i <- 1
p <- list()
for (column in names(temp23_before6)) {
  l <-length(unique(temp23_before6[, column]))
  if (l < 20 && l > 1) {
    colors <- factor(temp23_before6[, column])
    print(colors)
    p[[i]] <- ggplot(temp23_before6, aes(TIME, VALUE, colour=colors)) + 
      geom_point() + labs(title=column)

    i <- i + 1
  }
}

plot(p[[1]])
```

In the example you'll see that I removed the assignment of `column` to `cc` since we don't need that and I explicitly set the color variable to be used. If we run the above code, everything runs without error, but as the OP has noted, every plot is the exact same. In addition, we notice that the factor levels of the colors are identical on all plots and is equal to the factor levels of the last iteration. This got me thinking about how `ggplot` assigns the colors. So let's change `colors` to be something else and rerun a plot that has already been generated.

```
colors <- factor(20:30)
plot[[p1]]
```

This gives us an error, telling us that the aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5). This seems to imply that at the time of plotting, the data used for assigning the colors is drawn at that time and is not "saved". So, when you run your `multiplot` function, all of the graphs draw from the same data to assign the colors, which in your case is `temp23_before6[, column]` where `column` is now static and saved as the last column name.

Comment: It doesn't seem like `assign` solves the problem unfortunately. If I create 5 variables, I still then have to set color like `colour=get(paste0("colors_", i))` and `i` always equals to 5 when I run the code

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when I tried to implement the workaround. As a result, I deleted that portion of the answer.